# copy files and rename them from list

Tags: file, copy, rename

I have one program need to make a lot of copy of them,. For example 9 copie in 1 folder.

Then I need to rename this copies in different name get the name from the *.txt file. I try to make it  but  i cant make it good.

```vb
Private Sub renameFilesInFolderChronologically()
  Dim sourcePath As String = "e:\temp\demo"
  Dim searchPattern As String = "*.txt"

  Dim curDir As New DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)

  Dim i As Integer = 0
  For Each fi As FileInfo In curDir.GetFiles(searchPattern).OrderBy(Function(num) num.CreationTime)
    File.Move(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, "txtFile_" & i & ".txt"))
    i += 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Please add a tag with your programming language first (seems to be vb.net) and don't repeat keywords from the headline.